# .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle fails to install with error 0x80072efd

Tags: windows, .net

Trying to install the *.NET Core Windows Server Hosting* bundle (`DotNetCore.1.0.5_1.1.2-WindowsHosting.exe`) on Windows 2008 R2 fails with

```
Error 0x80072efd: Process returned error: 0x2efd
```

Answer (score 1):

- The server in question did not have Internet access (by design).
- Trawling the various logs in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp` showed this

  `Error 0x80072efd: Failed to send request to URL: https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/F/0/1F01DD22-748C-41A7-89DE-54D64355CDA6/vc_redist.x64.exe, trying to process HTTP status code anyway.`
- Downloaded the package manually and installed
- Retried the original installer and it worked